# Registration through kapsel on smp

Tags: sapui5, sap-smp

I am using kapsel to register since I can know if the user is already registered.But I am getting the init cannot be called..  Please help me through this

I added all the plugins according to document provided by sybase
http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc01993.0300/doc/html/LogonController-js.html

```
var defaultContext = {   "serverHost" : "192.168.254.159",   "https" : "false",   "serverPort" : "8080", };
sap.Logon.init(logonSuccess, logonError, appId, defaultContext);



error : uncaught typeerror cannot call method 'init' of undefined
It seems
```

Comment: Got the solution, All I need to do is load plugins using appropriate cordova version to relevant version of SMP SDK SP(version).

Comment: Probably, you could explain your answer a little bit. I have the exact same problem and no idea what you are talking about!

Comment: Note: If you are going to answer your own question with a right answer you get more points I guess

Answer (score 1):

Your Kapsel plugin does not seem to be correctly loaded.

Here is the command to add it as a Cordova plugin: `cordova plugin add <full path to directory containing Kapsel plugins>\logon`